# Displace Modifier Not Turning my Sphere Into a Blob

Tags: modifiers, displacement

I've exported an STL from Rhino / Grasshopper and would like to turn my sphere into a blob shape. As I'm new to Blender, I asked around and someone suggested the Displace Modifier with a cloud texture.

File: https://blend-exchange.com/b/WJ3XEPme

I'd like to apply a blob shape like this to my current sphere:
[image]

But unfortunately, I get a wrinkled paper effect instead:
[image]

Does anyone know what settings I should modify to get an effect more like this?
[image]

Thank you!

Comment: hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Sure thing @moonboots the file is https://blend-exchange.com/b/WJ3XEPme

[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=WJ3XEPme" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/WJ3XEPme/)

Comment: Hi. Please don't post essential information like links, file downloads or additional details in the comments section where it can be easily missed. Instead edit them into your original post with the [Edit] button above. Comments are transitory by nature, are hard to index or search for, and may be erased at any moment.

Comment: Even without the file I would say, you haven't applied the scale to the sphere and therefore the settings might not look like expected... or no, the other way round: the scale is applied, but the sphere is really large and the settings would rather work on a smaller sphere.

Comment: Weight painting would solve it i guess

Comment: @MehdiBelhous How would weight painting solve this? Can you elaborate on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sphere is simply too large to show a real effect of the *Displacement* modifier settings.

The size of the *Clouds* texture for example is 0.55, that's almost nothing with a sphere of 100 m in diameter. I've set the *Size* to 20 (you have to do it manually, the slider only goes up to 2) and the *Strength* in the modifier to 20 as well (and set the object to *Shade Smooth*). This is the result:

[image: elizabeth sphere]